# Installation leads to black screen

Tags: installation

I have a new Asus F501A-XX385H laptop, with Windows 8 preinstalled and Intel HD 3000 onboard graphics, which seems to be problematic. No matter what I do, trying to install Ubuntu from a USB stick (the laptop has no optical drive) leads me to a black screen with no cursor. In fact, choosing any of the options leads to a black screen. SecureBoot and FastBoot are disabled. I have already tried:

- Using two different USB sticks, with either 12.04.2 or 13.04. I can use them just fine on another computer (live session starts, etc.).
  Curiously, in the new computer I get a black and white, GRUB-like
  screen, while in the other I get the usual one with the different
  options.
- Increasing the screen's brightness.
- Using different recommended kernel options I have found for other cases
  (nomodeset,nolapic,acpi=off,acpi_osi=Linux,acpi_backlight=vendor,
  even i915.modeset=1 and i915.modeset=0).

Any ideas on how I could fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From what you mention I that your laptop is running in UEFI mode and your other computers in BIOS mode , so your usb is booting fine in your other BIOS computers but not in your new UEFI Laptop.

Thats why you get normal boot screen in your BIOS computer.

UEFI is a new boot mechanism and replacement for BIOS.

You need to tell how you made the USB drive, and it should be made in such a way that it runs on UEFI systems.